# OS X: how to keep the computer from sleeping during a ssh session

Tags: ssh, osx, power-management

When I *ssh* into a **OS X** computer on my network the session lasts until the **OS X** goes into **sleep** mode.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening during my *SSH* session, apart from physically bumping the mouse or typing keys, or manually disabling the sleep function?

EDIT: The ssh session would normally be a simple sshfs mount.

Comment: Wouldn't you also want to prevent it going to sleep *before* your SSH session?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not a out-of-the-box solution but it will possibly work if no one other comes up with a solution :-)

You can manipulate the power management settings with the command `pmset`. See the [manpage](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html) for more information about it.

The interesting setting we want to manipulate is *sleep*:

> sleep - system sleep timer (value in
>   minutes, or 0 to disable)

So we can use the following commands:

```
sudo pmset sleep 25      # go to sleep after 25 minutes
sudo pmset sleep 0       # disable sleep
```

Now we have to trigger these commands after a login and logut. If I remember this right, Bash is the default shell for Mac OS X which brings us to these two files:

> ```
>    ~/.bash_profile
>           The personal initialization file, executed for login shells
>    ~/.bash_logout
>           The individual login shell cleanup file, executed when a login shell exits
> ```

Edit or create them in your home directory and add the appropriate commands.
If you want, save the current sleep value in a temporary file and restore it from it afterwards.

The last problem to solve is the password prompt of sudo. To give your user the permission to invoke pmset without any password, edit your /etc/sudoers with sudoedit.
You need to use the `NOPASSWD` tag. If this is new for you, have a look at the [sudoers manual](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudoers.man.html).

Comment: would this method work if the ssh connection was only a sshfs mount?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think sshfs will open a login shell, so this won't work with sshfs.

Answer (score 14):

This allowed me to use my mac over SSH no matter what, as long as the mac is connected to a power source.

[image: System Preferences, Energy saver, Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off]

Everything gets shut down when the mac gets off its power source, so you don't have to worry about battery life.

Comment: This option is useless on macOS Sierra. My iMac sleeps regardless of this setting, wakes on SSH access, and then sleeps immediately after SSH logout. It's really annoying.

Comment: This answer finally solved my issue after fiddling around with ~/.ssh/config for hours on a Mojave iMac

Answer (score 10):

To use SSH to open a shell on a remote OSX machine and prevent it from sleeping for the duration of the SSH session:

```
$ ssh -t me@mymacbook caffeinate -i bash
```

Answer (score 8):

OS X's built in pmset utility has a setting that may do what you want. Check the `pmset` manpage for the `ttyskeepawake` setting and accompanying explanation.

The following command will probably do what you want:

```
sudo pmset -c ttyskeepawake 1
```

The `-c` flag makes this setting active specifically when the computer is running on AC power (as opposed to battery or UPS power), and `ttyskeepawake 1` prevents the computer from sleeping during an active tty session (presumably a remote one). It *will* allow sleep if the session has been inactive for longer than the sleep timer, but if that's an issue, maybe the computer shouldn't be set to sleep at all.

Answer (score 6):

Since Mac OS X 10.8, you should be able to use the [`caffeinate(8)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/caffeinate.8.html) command.

Try `caffeinate -s ssh server.example.com`.

Comment: The OP is trying to keep the *remote* Mac (i.e., the ssh server) from sleeping.  Unless I am mistaken, your example will only prevent sleep on the client's terminal.

Answer (score 4):

I added the following script in `.bash_profile`

```
if expr "$(ps -o comm= $PPID)" : '^sshd:' > /dev/null; then
  caffeinate -s $SHELL --login
  exit $?
fi
```

If the process is a direct child of a ssh daemon, run a same shell via the `caffeinate` command to prevent the system from sleeping during the ssh session.

Comment: manpage link now dead?

Comment: @pjc50 Thanks. I removed the link.

Answer (score 2):

A web search for *mac prevent sleep* comes up with a lot of good information on utilities and tricks you can use.

However, in your situation, I suspect that what you really want to do is to have a separate ssh session that runs a very simple command-line program that prevents the Mac from sleeping. Apple gives the complete source code in [Technical Q&A 1160: Preventing sleep](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa2004/qa1160.html). (Unfortunately, this page is broken on Apple's site at present, but you can pull up a copy from Google's cache.)

I haven't tested to see if this program can be run successfully from an ssh session, but it looks like it could.

Note that sshfs implementations typically don't stay logged into the remote system all the time, and just run a session when they want a file or directory. So you need a separate ssh session, running in a minimized terminal window, to run the insomnia program.

The advantage of this approach is that you don't need to use sudo, or mess with the system power management settings.